# grails - tell me if anything is dirty?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Grails provides an [isDirty method](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/isDirty.html) that can be called on domain objects.  How would one modify the Grails domain model system, such that one could simply call a method, to find out if any domain objects are dirty.

I'm struggling with some "unsaved transient instance" errors that I haven't been able to nail down, and it'd be great to know what's dirty.  Is there an elegant way to do this with groovy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to BootStrap.groovy:

```
import org.hibernate.Session

Session.metaClass.isDirty = { ->
   delegate.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey.values().any { it.isDirty() }
}
```

This adds an `isDirty()` method to Hibernate sessions that checks that top-level instances or instances in collections are dirty and you can use it with `withSession`, e.g.

```
boolean dirty = SomeDomainClass.withSession { session -> session.isDirty() }
```

or if you have access to the `sessionFactory` bean (e.g. from a `def sessionFactory` dependency injection)

```
boolean dirty = sessionFactory.currentSession.isDirty()
```

Comment: Thanks for this code Burt and all you do to support the Grails community in general.  Hope you had a nice New Years.  Please note I added a slight variant to your code (please change if I there is a mistake in it).  Unfortunately I still can't nail down my error.  I've got a domain class A, that hasMany B.  When I try to save B, it tells me it references an unsaved transient instance: A, even though I just saved the only instance of A I'm dealing with at the moment.  I changed B to have a belongsTo A, so perhaps I should just totally leave B alone now?  I should never try to save B directly?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Burt's answer, one might also do:

```
   Session.metaClass.whatsDirty = { ->
       def everythingDirty = []
       delegate.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey.values().each { if (it.isDirty()) everythingDirty.add(it) }
       return everythingDirty
    }
```

Comment: Not tested, but this is more compact:  `Session.metaClass.whatsDirty = { ->
   delegate.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey.values().collect { it.isDirty() }
}`

Comment: For future travellers here I think that should be: `Session.metaClass.whatsDirty = { -> delegate.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey.values().findAll { it.isDirty() } }` (ie. `findAll` instead of `collect`). A helpful bit of code, though.